# Will SSIS extract data through itself in all circumstances?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

When developing a Azure SQL Data warehouse with SSIS. We have 2-phrase steps 
to 1) copy data source to staging table, 2) copy staging table to report table

My question is, will SSIS actually extract data through it's own server, even it knows source & target are the same OLE DB provider? Or it's smart enough to use "SELECT INTO FROM SELECT * FROM .."? This makes a difference to us as Azure calculate the cost on exporting data out from Azure, and we have a lot of similar copying actions in DW, and SSIS is the only machine on-premise.

We could define a series of SQL statement tasks with nested query but it's hard to manage for TransactionOption in such a quantity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it will do this as SSIS was designed with so many hooks into the pipe that it is counter-intuitive to try to optimize by skipping it.

You could however use TSQL to do the Select Into and keep processing on the same server as the database engine.

If you need to switch between the two methods you can have a parameter to your package and conditional execution via constraints.